# Mongodb and springboot how do I run specific queries

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

My account.java model is just this

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString

@Document(collection="Account")
public class Account {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;


}
```

here is my repo

```
package com.example.demo.repository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

import com.example.demo.model.Account;



public interface AccountRepository extends MongoRepository<Account, Integer> {


    @Query("update Account u set u.username = ?1 where u.username = ?2")
    void changeUsername(String firstname, String currentName);


}
```

This causes the error

```java
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
update User u set u.username = "_param_1" where u.username = "_param_2"
```

I'm trying to this strictly using query but how? Is there a way to use mysql query style with mongodb because thats all i'm familiar with currently. If not. How would I do this with a mongodb query?